# Angular 5 : All Material elements not known in html file

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

So everything was alright until I uninstalled a module I just installed before (daterange picker) using npm uninstall --save.

Since then, for a mysterious reason, in one of my components (and only one), all material elements are no longer known, however it still runs.

So the HTML of the component is full of errors as you can see:
[my HTML full of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joVON.png)

But in all my others components, I have no error, everything is alright, my material elements are all known.
And as I said earlier, it sill runs with npm start, I don't have any error.

I work with Visual Studio Code.

Here are my dependencies (the component having errors is NouvelleDemandecomponent):

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import 'hammerjs';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { ActusComponent } from './actus/actus.component';
import { NouvelledemandeComponent } from './nouvelledemande/nouvelledemande.component';
import { CustFileComponent } from './cust-file/cust-file.component';
import { ListFilesComponent } from './list-files/list-files.component';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    ActusComponent,
    NouvelledemandeComponent,
    CustFileComponent,
    ListFilesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And my sharedModule which contains all my material elements:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatTooltipModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatTooltipModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatTooltipModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Comment: Have you closed opened you vs code?

Comment: I did it already

Comment: It's looks like you have installed some visual studio code extensions

Comment: Well finally aftera day it was fixed... Thanks anyway